# How to have a field member which is persisted in another schema?

Tags: mysql, mapping, jdo, datanucleus

Assume the following (I'm using MySQL)

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class TclRequest2 {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Persistent(column = "userid")
    @Column(jdbcType = "INTEGER", length = 11, allowsNull = "false", defaultValue = "1")
    private Member member; // This object table is in another schema
    // Getters and setters
}
```

The field `member` is persisted in another schema. I could solve this by specifying the "catalog" attribute in the `Member` class's `@PersitentCapable` annotation but that would kill the flexibility of specifying the schema name in the properties file I'm using since I'm configuring jdo in a properties file.

Thank you.